# Accessing parent.document from iFrame using jQuery, getting 'Access is denied' in IE?

Tags: jquery, iframe, parent

I have a parent document that creates an iFrame and loads content.

I'm using jQuery on the iframe document to access elements on the parent document and change their styling, like this

```
popBox = $('#slideshow_popOutBox', parent.document);
$(popBox).css({'border':'none','background':'transparent'});
```

On my development server this works in every browser I've tested (IE 7-9, FF 3.6-11, Chrome, Safari)

When the client puts it on their server, it fails in IE with 'Access is denied'. The line it fails on is

```
popBox = $('#slideshow_popOutBox', parent.document);
```

Chrome fails, but actually outputs something more useful:

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://www.domain.com/default_PrestitialAd.asp from frame with URL http://www.domain.com/ads/Prestitial/index.html. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

The domains and protocols match. I'm checking with the client regarding the ports.

What I'm really wondering is if there is some javascript on the parent that is preventing the iframe from accessing any of its elements. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: No, if you are getting that error, the iframe's domain doesn't match the parent page's domain. Keep in mind a different subdomain also qualifies as a different domain entirely.

Comment: They're not included here because it's the client's development server, but the domains are identical. Same subdomain too.

Comment: Does making that read `window.parent.document` may any difference at all?

Comment: I can try it. Part of the real problem for me is I don't have any direct access to their server so anything I change has to be sent to them to be put n their server. Something along those lines that I  just discovered was that entering $('#slideshow_popOutBox', parent.document); in Chrome console returns 'null', but entering parent.document.getElementById('slideshow_popOutBox'); returns the HTML element.